# PyUSB ctrl_transfer gives [Errno 32] Pipe error

Tags: python, serial-communication, pyusb

I am new to PyUSB and I am trying to communicate with [this](https://download.tek.com/datasheet/2SseriesMSO-Datasheet-48W738576.pdf) oscilloscope using my Laptop via USB. I have established the initial communication with the scope but I cannot send any commands to the scope as I am getting a "Pipe error".

This is my code:

```
import time
import csv
import usb.core
import usb.util
import array
import codecs
import sys


# Vendor and Product ID is obtained from the device datasheet.
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x699, idProduct=0x105)

# Check whether the device is found.
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device is not found!')
else:    
    print(dev) #Used to find out the IN and OUT endpoint addresses.
    dev.reset() #Resetting the device.
    dev.set_configuration()#Getting the device ready.
  
usb.util.claim_interface(dev, 0)
time.sleep(1)

cmd = '*IDN?' # This is the command    
dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 0x04, 0, 0, cmd, 1000)
time.sleep(1)
```

As seen in the code, I am trying to send '*IDN?' to the scope to get manufacturer and other such identification details about the scope. This is the error that I am getting (happens due to dev.ctrl_transfer()):

```
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Work_related\Read_data_from_oscilloscope\Read_data_from_MSO.py", line 28, in <module>
    dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 0x04, 0, 0, cmd, 1000)

  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 1089, in ctrl_transfer
    self.__get_timeout(timeout))

  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 901, in ctrl_transfer
    timeout))

  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 604, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])

USBError: [Errno 32] Pipe error
```

I tried ctrl_transfer() because the data that I get using read() and write() is garbage. I don't know why. This is the code using read() and write():

```
cmd = 'DATE?'
dev.write(1, cmd, 1000)
time.sleep(1)
data = dev.read(0x81, 128)
time.sleep(1)
data = list(data)
data_in_unicode = [chr(i) for i in data]
print(''.join(data_in_unicode))
```

How can I remove the "Pipe Error" issue? Any help is greatly appreciated.